# "the following photo is the photo of" or "the following is the photo of..."

Tags: word-usage

Is it common in English to use one word twice, for instance, is it true to say:
"the following photo is the photo of our previous home"
or is it better to use the sentence below :
"the following is the photo of our previous home"
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

A sensible rule of thumb is to repeat a word when clarity requires it, but to avoid doing so if you can, for the sake of elegance.

Here, you can be both clear and concise:

> "The following photo is of our previous home".

Comment: Even better, use active voice: "The following photo shows our previous home."

Comment: @M.K.Hunter - Agreed.